# Closing aiohttp.ClientSession on parent object destruction

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing a CLI for accessing REST API. I have defined `aiohttp.ClientSession` class field `_client_session` in async init method.

How do I close the `aiohttp.ClientSession` properly? If I do:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp


class Profile:                                                                    
    def __init__(self, loop):                                                     
        self._loop = loop                                                         
        self._client_session = None                                               

    def __del__(self):                                                            
        self._loop.run_until_complete(self._client_session.close())              

    async def async_init(self):
        self._client_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()                           

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, loop):
        self = cls(loop)
        await self.async_init()
        return self


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
profile = loop.run_until_complete(Profile.create(loop))                          
loop.close()
```

I get this:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Profile.__del__ of <profile.Profile object at 0x7f8ab82e15c0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rominf/projects/profile/profile/__init__.py", line 197, in __del__
File "/home/rominf/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 444, in run_until_complete
File "/home/rominf/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 358, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession.close' was never awaited
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f8ab43bf588>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f8ab28a06a8>, 11519.944147989)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f8ab43bf3c8>
```

I understand this happens for a reason: I close the `loop` before garbage collector deletes `profile`. The solution is to delete it manually with `del`, but I don't want to do this.

It there a way to register the future for execution just before event loop closing?

Comment: what about `__aenter__`/`__aexit__` methods?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, `__aexit__` is for async context managers, it's not called on object destruction. I still get: "Unclosed client session" error.

Comment: well, it seems that your event loop gets closed before closing `ClientSession`, can you show us more of your code?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio` doesn't support IO in destructors.
The same for constructors and properties.

The recommended way is adding `async with Profile` or `await profile.close()` support.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I don't want to implement the context manager for `Profile` because I will execute `Profile` methods in various parts of the code.
I ended up writing async `Profile.close`.

Comment: Different use cases requires different solutions.
That's why `aiohttp.ClientSession` supports both async context manager and async close methods.